# Wireshark shows CR being sent to a client from my server app but my program sends a CR to a different IP/Port than the client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a simple linux ansi c socket program that basically listens on a tcp port (infd), accepts a connection from one input device that stays connected (not my choice), then reads data byte by byte and when appropriate writes it to a third device (outfd). The third device requires that a carriage return be sent after every command. The only time it ever writes back to the input device is when it receives an "idle" message and I write back the response with the following in the main loop of the program.

```
unsigned char idle[3];  
idle[0]=0xF1;
idle[1]=0x00;
idle[2]=0xFF;

//idle message TCP only xF1x00xFF
if(recieved==0xF1){
    res = read(infd,&recieved,1);
    res = read(infd,&recieved,1);
    res = write(infd,idle,3);
```

}

The only place I write a carriage return occurs n a separate function so the file descriptor is a local variable.

```
int sendOutput(unsigned char *data, struct sockaddr_in *outaddr){
        int n,outfd;
    if ((outfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) <0) {
        fprintf(errorfd,"ERROR creating output socket to send out\n");
        fclose(errorfd);
        return(FALSE);
    }    

    if (connect(outfd, (struct sockaddr *)outaddr, sizeof(*outaddr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(errorfd,"ERROR connecting to out server (%i) %s \n",errno,strerror(errno));
        fflush(errorfd);
    }
    else{       
        n = write(outfd, data, strlen(data));
        if (n < 0) {
            fprintf(errorfd,"ERROR writing to out server (%i) %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
            fflush(errorfd);
        }
        write(outfd,"\r",1);            
        n=read(outfd,data,9);  //read back commandline prompt but do nothing with it
    }
    shutdown(outfd,SHUT_WR);
    close(outfd);   
    return(TRUE);   
}
```

When I run a packet trace I am seeing a carriage return (x0d) being sent to the client device from my device but my code only sends the writes that I listed above.  The manufacturer of the client device is "claiming" the CR is causing them problems.

I've checked and the carriage return is coming from my IP / MAC so I do not believe it is another device with a dupe IP sending it.

Any ideas how this could be possible?

The output device is receiving the data and CR so I am at a complete loss how the input device is getting sent a carriage return.  outfd is a socket that is opened written to and closed in a sperate function.  The data is passed in as is the prefilled socket structure (Different IP and Port than the infd socket).

Comment: What is `data`? What does it contain?

Comment: And if the only way to get a response is to send an "idle command", what happens with the `read` in your `sendOutput` function, if the `data` is *not* an "idle command"?

Comment: data is a command to send to the output system and will always contain a value or the function will not get called.  Basically my system is a translator between two other third party systems.  when I see lets say xxx from the input system I send yyy\r to the output system.

Comment: This code is incomplete, so we can only speculate, but out of curiosity, does the problem still occur if you comment out everything in `sendOutput` except the final `return`?

Comment: If no other command than this "idle" command will cause the server to respond, any other command will cause the `read` call to block, indefinitely.

Comment: The server sends my app data regardless of how the idle message is handled.